# How to log querys using MongoDB in Grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails, log4j

I'm trying to log the queries that my application is doing to MongoDB database, but I can't find how to do that, all I find about logging in grails is based on hibernate, but I need to check how some queries are being parsed and sent to mongoDB.

I'm using Grails 2.2.1 and MongoDB GORM plugin 1.2.0

Comment: You can use [mongosniff](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongosniff/). `logSql`(untested) may not be relevant here for MongoDB.

Comment: We've tried using mongosniff, but the queries from Grails are not being shown, just the ones ran directly in mongo console are shown

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#diaglog . It has various different settings for logging related operations.

Comment: Thanks! That works :) Using --diaglog=3 option and reading it with mongosniff. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it